# A Criterion For a Set To Have all the Atoms of a Boolean Algebra

Tags: elementary-set-theory, boolean-algebra

Let $\Omega$ be any set and let $\mathcal A$ be an algebra of sets in $\Omega$. An element $E\in \mathcal A$ is said to be an **atom** if there is no non-empty element $A\in \mathcal A$ such that $A\subsetneq E$. (By convention we allow $\emptyset$ also to be an atom.)

I am wondering if the following is true:

> Let $\mathcal A$ be an algebea of sets in a set $\Omega$. Let $\mathcal S\subseteq \mathcal A$ be such that the members of $\mathcal S$ are pairwise disjoint, and the algebra generated by $\mathcal S$ is same as $\mathcal A$. Then $\mathcal S$ contains all the non-empty atoms of $\mathcal A$.
>
> ***EDIT:*** I think that under the above hypothesis we can further claim that $\mathcal S$ has nothing else but atoms of $\mathcal A$.

Can somebody confirm if the above is true?

Thanks.

Comment: See my revised answer: your conjecture is correct if $\mathscr{A}$ is infinite, but it can fail for finite algebras.

Comment: Yes I am reading it. Thanks very much.

Comment: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s false if $\Omega$ is finite. Suppose that $\Omega=\{x_0,\ldots,x_n\}$, where $n\ge 1$, $\mathscr{A}=\wp(\Omega)$, and

$$\mathscr{S}=\big\{\{x_k\}:1\le k\le n\big\}\;.$$

For $k=1,\ldots,n$ let $C_k=\Omega\setminus\{x_k\}$; clearly each $C_k$ is in the algebra generated by $\mathscr{S}$, and $\bigcap_{k=1}^nC_k=\{x_0\}$, a non-empty atom of $\mathscr{A}$.

In general the algebra generated by the pairwise disjoint family $\mathscr{S}$ is isomorphic to the algebra of finite and cofinite subsets of $\mathscr{S}$. If $\mathscr{A}$ is infinite, $\mathscr{S}$ must also be infinite, and in that case the atoms of the algebra generated by $\mathscr{S}$ are precisely the elements of $\mathscr{S}$: they correspond to the singleton subsets of $\mathscr{S}$, which are the atoms of the algebra of finite and cofinite subsets of $\mathscr{S}$. Thus, $\mathscr{S}$ must consist precisely of the atoms of $\mathscr{A}$, which must be the algebra generated by its atoms.

Comment: But we also had an extra condition that the members of $\mathscr S$ are pairwise disjoint. This is not happening here. Isn't it?

Comment: @caffeinemachine: Oops: somehow I overlooked that condition.